Confusion on the hat-symbol in statistics
Learning about different notations in statistics is confusing me.
In a basic linear regression, we write:
$$Y = \beta_0 + \beta_1 X + \epsilon$$
$$\hat{y} = \hat{\beta}_0 + \hat{\beta}_1 X$$
$$\hat{\epsilon} = y - \hat{y}$$
This is because the error only exists in the theoretical model, hats on top of an estimated value, and the residual ($\hat{\epsilon}$) depends on an estimated quantity therefore it has a hat.
Beyond this, I am getting very confused.
For example, are both of these statements correct about the marginal distribution of $Y$?

$$Y \sim N(X^T \beta, \sigma^2) \implies E(Y) = X^T \beta$$
$$Y \sim N(X^T \hat{\beta}, \hat{\sigma}^2) \implies E(Y) = X^T \beta$$

And are these statements correct about the conditional distributions of $Y$?

$$E(Y \mid X) = \beta_0 + \beta_1 X$$
$$E(Y \mid X, \beta, \sigma^2) = \beta_0 + \beta_1 X$$
$$E(Y \mid X, \hat{\beta}, \hat{\sigma}^2) = \beta_0 + \beta_1 X$$

In general, I know that once you take the expectation of something on the left hand side, the right hand side loses the hat. But I am wondering that perhaps some of these statements are actually equivalent to each other, its just that statement 1) (in conditional and marginal statements) is shorthand notation whereas the other statements are actually equivalent to 1)?
I would appreciate any assistance in clarifying confusions about the hat symbols and expectations.

You can think of $\hat{\epsilon}$ quite literally as an estimate of $\epsilon$. It's our best linear estimate of it under the usual assumptions. It's not necessary to say we put a hat on it merely "because it depends on $\hat{y}$" - it merits a hat  in a more direct sense. Your comment to that effect is mainly an aside but it's perhaps something of a distraction there.

I can't figure out what you mean by your first (2) and (3), because $\hat\beta$ depends on $Y.$

I am accustomed to seeing $Y\sim\operatorname N(X\beta, \sigma^2 I_n)$ where $X$ is a matrix with $n$ rows and $I_n$ is the $n\times n$ identity matrix, and $\beta$ is a column vector with as many rows as $X$ has columns.
In this notation $X,$ $\beta,$ and $\sigma^2$ are treated as constants, i.e. not random. In reality, if the experiment is replicated, you may get all new values of $X,$ so $X$ is random, but in this problem it is treated as not random because one is considering the conditional distribution of $Y$ given $X.$ (And in some cases, the experimenter controls the $X$ values, so $X$ stays the same in a replication.) For that reason, it is at best redundant to write something like $\operatorname E(Y\mid X, \beta, \sigma^2).$
As for your statement #3, see whuber's comment.
BTW, in addition to $\epsilon,$ you can write $\varepsilon,$ which is less likely to be confused with $\in.$ And easier to read, I think.
